# API Platform "Unexpected non-object value for object property."

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

I am trying to use API Platform serialization with calculated field as in here https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#calculated-field

Here is the code

```
/**
 * @Groups({
 *     "read:actionJeu"
 * })
 */
public function getTimePassed(){
    return 4;
}
```

The normalization context is `normalizationContext={"groups"={"read:actionJeu"}, "enable_max_depth"=true}`

The problem is that when I do `return 4`, it shows this error[image]

But when I change the return to something else (for example `return new \DateTime('now')` ), I get it working.

I wonder why this is happening, I tried with string too, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I supose that your entity property $timePassed is type of DateTime. Return type of method getTimePassed() also must be the DateTime type. You can change type of property $timePassed to int instead of DateTime or make your custom TimePassedSerializer service.

```
/** this **/
private int $timePasede;
/** insted of this **/
private DateTime $timePasede
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by the API Platform core package version.

Try installing version **2.6.8** or **2.6.6**.

I was dealing with the same thing on the 2.6.7.

Answer (score -1):

The example defines the return type of the function with `: int` at the end, so that it's clear that this function will return an integer.

I guess that api-platform will expect an object per default until a different return type has been defined.

So this should work from my understanding. Note that I haven't tested it because I don't have the possibility for it right now.

```
/**
 * @Groups({
 *     "read:actionJeu"
 * })
 */
public function getTimePassed(): int {
    return 4;
}
```